# Filtering MDX query with current year & month using Now()

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube, ssas-2008

How can I filter data in MDX with current Year & Month?

What I did so far is:

```
WHERE strtomember{ [Time Dim].[FSCL YEAR].&["+Format(now(), "yyyy")+"], [Time Dim].[FSCL MONTH].&["+Format(now(), "m")+"] }
```

but it is not working.

Comment: What is the result you get for the first query? What is the result of the second Query? Is `[Measures].[Measure]` a calculated measure? If so, could you share its definition?

Comment: Nothing is calculated here. All are simple Measures & dimensions. I apologize as I can not share actual MDX here.

Comment: @Adita As you are using `[Dimension].[Dim].[Dim].ALLMEMBERS` and not `[Dimension].[Dim].[Dim].MEMBERS`, I would assume that the difference is in the calculated measures of this hierarchy? Otherwise, if no calculated members are involved, then the results should match.

Comment: Wait, i will take another try, thanks for suggestion

Comment: Yes, you are right. Its working better now.

Comment: Please note that question is edited here, so you may found comments irrelevant of question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StrToMember` is a function that takes one argument, which is a string. You seem to try to pass it a set, as you are using curly braces. The correct syntax would be:

```
WHERE ( 
      strtomember("[Time Dim].[FSCL YEAR].&[" + Format(now(), "yyyy") + "]"),
      strtomember("[Time Dim].[FSCL MONTH].&[" + Format(now(), "m") + "]")
      )
```

The argument to `StrToMember` in both cases ia a string concatenated from fix strings like `"[Time Dim].[FSCL YEAR].&["` and `"]"`, as well as the result of the `Format` function.

Comment: Tuples or set must use same hierarchy in the function error for where clause.

Comment: @Aditya Oh, I see. They are from different hierarchies. hence you must put them into a tuple in the `WHERE` condition, not in a set. I corrected that.

Comment: I do not see where it would make sense. `Generate` loops over a set and either returns a string containing the concatenation of the strings returned from each loop iteration, or the union of the sets returned from each loop iteration. Where d you see the set to loop over? Where do you see a string or set result? I only see a tuple result.

Comment: Your error message states "in the function error for where clause". I see no call to the function "Error" in my code. Probably there is something wrong in your adaptation of my code to your case.

Comment: Hey really sorry, I used old one, its now working but no measures are displayed, null only. Probably Month formatting I have to check.

Comment: My months are like 1, 2, 3 so on including Unknown

Comment: Format(now(), "m") , its "MM". Working proper now.